# Scaffolding/Mocking a REST service for client side development

Tags: rest, webclient, scaffolding

There are two teams that are working on a REST service and a web client separably.
Is there a tool that scaffolds a REST service given a configuration can return a predetermined result for a URI+VERB combination?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same thing. All I have found so far is this project [SOAP/REST Mock Service](http://sourceforge.net/p/soaprest-mocker/wiki/Home/)
but I haven't tested it yet.